How to inject a mock instance to Rust trait while holding on to reference of that mock
I made this Rust struct called Oracle that can answer any question
/// Oracle is a wise entity that can answer questions
pub struct Oracle {
    source: Rc<dyn WisdomSource>,
}

impl Oracle {
    pub fn new() -> Oracle {
        Oracle {
            source: Rc::new(Magic8Ball)
        }
    }

    pub fn ask(&self, question: &String) -> String {
        self.source.ask(question)
    }
}

The Oracle has a source of wisdom that it uses to seek answers to questions.
/// Trait for a source of wisdom
#[mockall::automock]
trait WisdomSource {
    fn ask(&self, question: &String) -> String;
}

/// Default source of wisdom implementation
struct Magic8Ball;

impl WisdomSource for Magic8Ball {
    fn ask(&self, question: &String) -> String {
        let answers = vec!["yes", "no", "maybe", "ask again later"];

        let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
        question.hash(&mut hasher);
        let hash_value = hasher.finish();
        let index = (hash_value % 4) as usize;
        
        answers[index].to_string()
    }    
}

For making unit test for this oracle, I will inject a mockup of WisdomSource
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[test]
    fn test_sage() {
        let mut mockup_source = MockWisdomSource::new();
        mockup_source.expect_ask().times(1).return_const("42".to_string());
        
        let source: Rc<dyn WisdomSource> = Rc::new(mockup_source);
        
        let sage = Oracle{source};
        let answer = sage.ask(&"What is the meaning of life?".to_string());

        assert_eq!(answer, "42");
        
        // Check that the mockup was called
        mockup_source.checkpoint();  // How to get access get reference to the mockup_source?

    }
}

The last line of unit test doesn't compile because ownership of 'mockup_source' was transferred to RC 'source'.
I cannot use take reference from RC because that trait does not have checkpoint() -method.
AFAIK, I cannot upcast '&dyn WisdomSource' to '&MockWisdomSource'
What is the correct way to inject mock while holding on to something that enables using those mock features?

You can share ownership with Rc, just keep a Rc<MockWisdomSource> around and simply clone it (and coerce to dyn) when creating the oracle. However, you would still have a problem calling .checkpoint() since you can't get mutable access through Rcs - you can't mutate while someone else (i.e. the oracle) still has a handle on it. Is this the end of the test and you can drop the oracle?

Thanks @kmdreko.
Assuming I understood your comment correctly, I posted it as an answer. Is that what you were thinking of?
Even if I would scope out the Oracle, I can't get mutable access to that mock after ownership has moved to RC. Therefore I would have to wrap mock into RefCell.
Is this the best way to achieve this?

RefCell is one option, though it forced you to change the structure of Oracle just to accommodate your test. If the oracle were dropped, there would be only one Rc handle remaining from which you can use .get_mut() or .into_inner() to access the inner value.

Thanks @kmdreko for the followup. To AFAIK, Rc<MockWisdomSource> does not have .get_mut() nor any other mutable access to MockWisdomSource. Non that I know of - that is.

I linked to the documentation, but you are right that you can't call it as a method - that's my mistake. You'd have to call it explicitly like Rc::get_mut(&mut mockup_rc) instead.

Thank you @kmdreko, I think I now understand what you meant. I added a new answer. That new approach seems better.

kmdreko's hint seems to work.
Oracle now owns RC<RefCell>
pub struct Oracle {
    source: Rc<RefCell<dyn WisdomSource>>,
}

impl Oracle {
    pub fn new() -> Oracle {
        Oracle {
            source: Rc::new(RefCell::new(Magic8Ball))
        }
    }

    pub fn ask(&self, question: &String) -> String {
        self.source.borrow_mut().ask(question)
    }
}

Then at unit test, I will holdon to RC of RefCell of the mock and inject clone of that RC downcasted to Oracle
#[test]
fn test_sage() {
    let mockup_rc = Rc::new(RefCell::new(MockWisdomSource::new()));
    mockup_rc.borrow_mut().expect_ask().times(1).return_const("42".to_string());

    let source = Rc::clone(&mockup_rc) as Rc<RefCell<dyn WisdomSource>>;        
    let sage = Oracle{source};
    
    let answer = sage.ask(&"What is the meaning of life?".to_string());

    assert_eq!(answer, "42");
    
    // Check that the mockup was called
    mockup_rc.borrow_mut().checkpoint();
}


Although this is the technical solution to your problem, you shouldn't change production code "just" to make unit tests work. You should ask yourself why wisdom source is shared in the first place. Sounds like an OOP-ish approach. Could Oracle be the unique owner? This is possibly the case with most strategy-like patterns.

Thanks @fdan for your insight. We found a better solution in comments section of original post. Oracle could be unique owner but I couldn't think of way to do that with Oracle code being testable. Real WisdomSource is non-deterministic and unsuitable for unit test. Also, the unit test needs to hold on to reference to mockup to verify that expected method was called by calling the mockup's checkpoint method after the test.

Based on the followup discussion with kmdrenko, better solution was found. I didn't want to replace first answer because it had some discussion.
In this solution use of that Rc clone is isolated to own scope and Rc::get_mut is used to get mutable access to mock after there are no other Rc's referring to it.
#[test]
fn test_sage() {
    let mut mock_source = MockWisdomSource::new();
    mock_source.expect_ask().times(1).return_const("42".to_string());

    let mut mockup_rc = Rc::new(mock_source);

    // Scope to drop Oracle before checking the mockup
    {
        let source = Rc::clone(&mockup_rc) as Rc<dyn WisdomSource>;        
        let oracle = Oracle{source};
        
        let answer = oracle.ask(&"What is the meaning of life?".to_string());

        assert_eq!(answer, "42");
    }
     
    // Check that the mockup was called
    let mock_ref = Rc::get_mut(&mut mockup_rc).unwrap();
    mock_ref.checkpoint();        
}

